# Assumptions in two balls falling experiment

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum

A typical undergraduate physics class problem to demonstrate the effects of conservation of momentum is to have two balls of different mass falling one above the other (the largest mass below) to the ground and show that the top mass rises to a large height.

In analyzing the problem one usually assume that the bottom ball collides elastically first and travels upwards before hitting the second ball while it is travelling downwards.

This assumption is often justified by that the balls cannot colide before the bottom ball has hit the ground. In the limit the objects are perfectly rigid the interaction time between the ground and bottom mass goes to zero and the necessary gap between the balls for them to travel in the opposite direction goes to zero as well.

But if they are real objects then the top ball will hit the bottom ball while it is still being decellerated and deformed and the center of mass travelling downwards (provided gap is small enough). Is it possible to say anything general about what results using just momentum and energy? Or do you have to resort to continuum mechanics and see what happens?

Any link to an analysis is appreciated

Comment: It's possible to say a great deal about them generally. What are you wanting to know?

Comment: It is very easy to make the experiment realistic (and more useful for actual understanding), by leaving a well defined gap between the two balls. Thanks to the availability of video recording equipment (a typical physics classroom today has approx. 2n digital video cameras with n being the number of students) the event can be reconstructed very precisely.

Comment: @Asher - for example: can you predict how high it will go as a function of masses and inital mechanical energy? Is it dependent on the (nonlinear/visco-) elastic properties?